# Centering an embedded Youtube video in my tabbed content box

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS for a class and have to create a mock business/store website.  After some research and experimenting I've managed to start creating a product page with a tabbed info box at the bottom (click tab for description to see description, another tab for specs, another for media etc.).  I have a YouTube video embedded in the media tab, but I can't figure out how to center it within the box I've created.  None of the things I've usually used to center content seem to work and I'm wondering what in my CSS I would need to change to get it working.

This is the HTML for the full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NextGen Games</title>
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords">
    <meta name="author" content="author">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- This is where you put your content.-->
    <header>
      <h1>testtesttesttest</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
        <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <main>
      <div class="boxart">
        <img src="boxart.jpg" alt="game title" height="500px">
      </div>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <h2><p class="title">Game Title</p></h2>
      <p class="system">System</p>
      <p class="price">$79.99</p>
    </aside>

    <div class="tabbed">
      <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
      <section>
        <h2>
          <label for="tabbed1">Description</label>
        </h2>
        <div>
          Content/description/etc
        </div>
      </section>

      <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed2" type="radio">
      <section>
        <h2>
          <label for="tabbed2">Specifications</label>
        </h2>
        <div>
          <p><span class="boldline">Platform:</span> platform</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">Release Date:</span> date</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">Developer:</span> dev</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">Publisher:</span> publisher</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">Genre:</span> genres</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">Number of Players:</span> #</p>
          <hr>
          <p><span class="boldline">File Size:</span> #</p>
          <hr>
          <img src="esrb" height=100px class="esrb">
          <p class="esrbtext">esrb</p>
          <p class="esrbtext">descriptors</p>
          <p class="esrbtext">etc</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed3" type="radio">
      <section>
        <h2>
          <label for="tabbed3">Media</label>
        </h2>
        <div>
          <iframe width="671" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zw47_q9wbBE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the full CSS for the page.

```
body {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
  /* navigation bar */
nav {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
nav a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #fff
}

/* product page layout */
.boxart {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20%;
}
.title {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 120%;
}
.system {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.price {
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

/* product info box */
.tabbed{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabbed > input {
  display: none;
}
.tabbed > input:not(:checked) + section > div {
  display: none;
}
.tabbed > section > h2 {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tabbed > section > div {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2.5em 0 0 -100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.0625);
  background: #fff;
}
.tabbed > section > h2 > label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.0625);
  background: #fff;
}
.tabbed > section > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tabbed > input:checked + section > h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.boldline {
  font-weight: bold;
}
hr {
  border-color: rgba(224,224,224,.09)
}
.esrb {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.esrbtext {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A common CSS trick for aligning images and videos is using the attribute `text-align`. Even though it's not intuitive (and trust me, most css isn't), it's probably the simplest solution for `<iframe>` and `<img>` tags.

You can apply `style="text-align: center"` to your `section`, or create a custom id/class for this purpose.

Another solution (probably a little more intuitive) is to create a wrapper `<div>` around your iframe, and focus on centering the div. I noticed that your code has css affecting all of your div's so that their `position`, `z-index` and `display` attributes are affected. That would conflict with this solution, since you'd need a "reseted" div.

Comment: adding the style to my section tag worked perfectly.  thank you!